# Sorting and displaying a list in a basic record-jar format that is stored in a text file based on additional data stored within the same list

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write a script that makes a sorted list out of items stored in this format:

&&
TASK:
PROJECT:
CONTEXT:
DUE_DATE:
COMPLETION_DATE:
PRIORITY:
%%

I have a pretty good idea of the logic behind what I'm trying to do, but I'm very new to Python so I'm struggling with the implementation. Here's what I have so far:

```
import sys
import getopt

#add function
if sys.argv[1] == 'add':
    try:
        f = open("todo.txt", "added")
        try:
            f.write("TASK:" + sys.argv[2] + "\n")
            project = raw_input("Please enter the project: ")
            f.write("PROJECT:" + project + "\n")
            context = raw_input("Please enter the context: ")
            f.write("CONTEXT:" + context + "\n")
            duedate = raw_input("Please enter the due date: ")
            f.write("DUE_DATE:" + duedate + "\n")
            completiondate = raw_input("Please enter the completion date: ")
            f.write("COMPLETEION_DATE:" + completiondate + "\n")
            priority = raw_input("Please enter the priority level")
            f.write("PRIORITY:" + priority + "\n")
        finally:
            f.close()
    except IOError:
        pass

#list function
if sys.argv[1] == 'list':
    listnum = 1
    try:
        with open("todo.txt", "r") as f:
                searchlines = f.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):  
                if "TASK:" in line: 
                    for l in searchlines[i:i+3]: 
                    print listnum, l[5:],   
                    listnum += listnum

    except IOError:
        pass

#complete function
if sys.argv[1] == 'complete':
    listName.pop(args[0]-1);#this pops it out and deletes it.  need to sort into order and from that list. delete that item
#by popping and it will be the -1 of the one from the list.
```

Now, my add function works fine. I understand that argeparse(sp?) would let me add all of the meta data with a single line, but I figured I'd keep it as simple as possible. My list function at the moment simply lists all of the items based on their order within the file, but it doesn't have any sort of filter functionality. It also doesn't display the meta data below TASK: lines.

What I want to do with my list function is to have the default action sort all items in the text file based on priority. I'd like to accept additional search "tags" in the same line, and have the list function generate a list of TASKS: who have any number of meta data that match any of the search tags, and I want the filtered list to also be sorted based on priority.

What I'm thinking is to use letter tags for priority (A, B, etc...) and traversing to each entry in the file. I would then compare the task name and all of the meta data to each filter tag. If a match occurs, I would check the priority, and display the entry if the priority is "A". If the priority is not "A", but a match occurs, I would make some sort of bool flag turn to 1 to let me know the program needs to traverse the list again while looking for the next level of priority.

The things I don't know how to do:

1. Traverse the list and look for match, then look at the priority.
2. Display the filtered or unfiltered list with the TASK: lines enumerated and all other lines indented and NOT enumerated.
3. How to have the program stop traversing the list once all valid list candidates for the particular filter have been displayed
4. Not let previously displayed entries trigger the bool that causes the program to keep looking for more entries.
5. If possible, I'd like complete to look for a given task name, and if found, delete the task name and the next 6 lines in the text file.

Thank you for any help you can provide!